# Hibernate COUNT function can't find column

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

Currently trying to run a COUNT function in Hibernate that simply returns a count of all platforms in the table.

```
Query<?> intQuery = session.createQuery("select count(platform) from
 UserPlatform");`
```

Hibernate output in console:

```
Hibernate: select count(userplatfo0_.PLATFORM) as col_0_0_ from OTS_SCHEMA.OTS_USER_PLATFORM_TBL userplatfo0_
```

However, I am continually met with the following error when I run the code:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1535)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1574)
    at com.ots.Utilities.getPrimaryUserPlatformFromWrapper(Utilities.java:677)
    at com.ots.Processor$3.run(Processor.java:194)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column not found: col_0_0_
```

The Hibernate model class:

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name="OTS_USER_PLATFORM_TBL")
@Scope("prototype")
public class UserPlatform {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="CWSID")
    private String cwsid;

    @Column(name="PLATFORM")
    private String platform;


    @Autowired
    public UserPlatform(String cwsid, String platform) {
        this.cwsid = cwsid;
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    public UserPlatform() {

    }
//getters&setters
}
```

I ***suspect*** Hibernate is looking for a mapping to col_0_0, but as col_0_0 is not a 'real' column, there is no mapping for it. How do we handle this problem in Hibernate?

Comment: Can you try with select count(*) instead?

Comment: Can you show the entity `UserPlatform`

Comment: `PLATFORM` is a column or another table relation ?

Comment: I tried with select count(*) & received the same error. Platorm is a column name within the table.

Comment: what is your db ?

Comment: @antoine.lange Postgres

Comment: @Matthew Can  you share `OTS_USER_PLATFORM_TBL` table structure also ?

Comment: Can you try `session.createQuery("select count(u) from
 UserPlatform u")`

Comment: I tried that with the same outcome, unfortunately.

Comment: Does `select count(userplatfo0_.PLATFORM) as col_0_0_ from OTS_SCHEMA.OTS_USER_PLATFORM_TBL userplatfo0_` work when you run it from `psql` or any other SQL client?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It works when ran directly on the db.

Answer (score 1):

- Your Hibernate model class is way off:
- Delete: @Repository
- Delete: @Scope
- Delete: @Autowired Constructor
- You need to show your real service code, i.e. where you execute the query.

Comment: Care to elaborate why? This is a Spring application.

Comment: This has nothing to do with it being a Spring application, Hibernate is a completely separate (through well integrated) library. You select entities with repositories (hence the @Repository annotation doesnt make sense). Also, Spring does not instantiate entities, Hibernate does. So ,Scope and  Autowired doesnt make any sense.

Comment: This is a bean for other parts of my application. Those annotations are simply part of the overall project, so I don’t understand your comment. Plus, removing such annotations does not solve the problem anyway.

Comment: How exactly is this a bean for other parts of your application? The thing is this: Your select count query is a basic query and seeing your basic 3-in-1 "entity/repository/bean" i have the impression that you have something misconfigured somewhere, which we will not find out unless you post more code.

Comment: I managed to get the query to work with a native query: `Query<?> intQuery = session.createNativeQuery("SELECT COUNT(OTS_USER_PLATFORM_TBL.ID) "
    + "FROM OTS_USER_PLATFORM_TBL");`